# Can I make an Archive Page Template in Joomla! 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am not pertaining to the category list of archives, but for the ARTICLE PAGE itself once it is archived.
Like a "single-{post_type}.php" on a Wordpress template where {post_type} is "archive".

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

Joomla archive article uses a separate layout in `com_content` component.
If you're planning to create a custom styles for archive articles you just need to do template override for `com_content`.

In Joomla articles are managing with a component called `com_content`.

you have to do a copy of `components/com_content/views/archive/` files to your template folder. `templates/your_templates/html/com_content/views/archive/`

This way you can create custom styles for the archive articles. Also Please consider an update for your Joomla Version 1.5 is already dead.

Hope its helps..

Comment: thanks! now i would like to configure the "upper" content. How do I configure the query used for an archive page.
In my `main.php` block, I would like to display `<span>Hello</span>` before calling out the archive page content.
Like `wp_query( 'post_type'=>'archive' )` in wordpress.
(Sorry, I'm a Wordpress user but I have to edit someone else's Joomla).

Comment: Joomla component concept is entirely different from WordPress page. Joomla components are MVC based so in your layout templates/your_temp/..view/archive/default.php this is the default layout it was rendering the archive article Here you don't need to write query for collecting archive article bcoz this layout will render only on archive article. If you want add some text before that just add it on default.php. hope its clear.

Comment: I just found the right query for archived articles
`if($this->article->state==-1):`
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Iam not sure its -1 . In Joomla 2.5 its 1- Published,2-Archived,-2 trashed,0-published so please make sure its -1 in J1.5. you're welcome